# Minimum number of deletions to make a string palindrome

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

I have a string consisting zeros and ones and I need to know how many deletions **from the beginning** I need to do in order to make a string a palindrome. I wrote a function to check if the string is palindrome (and iterate over each element) and it works, but I need complexity better than O(n^2). It will be probably O(n) with KMP algorithm but I have no idea how to use it in this case.
Can you help me?

Comment: As fascinating as I find this problem, I'm not convinced that SO is the best place for it.  Usually questions on Stack Overflow are focused on _specific programming questions_.  There are, no doubt, a variety of solutions to this problem and the _best_ one will often be open to opinion.

Comment: I don't need the best one. I need a better one (in terms of time complexity).

Comment: @Ignos You are right. This can indeed be solved using KMP. Reverse the string and run KMP. Then the farthest index having value = index/2 will be the length of longest palindrome.

Comment: But I don't know how since the pattern in changing when I delete chars.